# Executing while loop issues KSH

Tags: unix, while-loop, ksh

I'm trying to execute a ksh where in the file it contains

```sh
    a = 0
    max = 25
    while [[$a -ne $max]];
    do
           echo "$a"
           a = $((a+5))
    done
```

It's giving me an error

```
"[[0: not found [No such file or directory]"
```

I will check the while loop and it says 2 brackets are needs and ne is for numerical which I did.....I don't know why it is not working....

Comment: have a look at this link https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/While_loop

Comment: `[[` and `]]` must have spaces around them. When you use `-ne`, use single `[`and `]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```sh
a=0
max=25
while [ $a -ne $max ];  #Changed here 
do
       echo "$a"
       a=$((a+5))
done
```

Answer (score 0):

For integers you can use

```
max=25
for (( a=0; a<max; a+=5 )); do
   echo "a=$a"
done
```